# c++ virtual function performance

Tags: c++, performance, virtual

I have two classes `foo` and `bar` where one is a superclass of the other, and they both have a method `hello_world`.

```
class foo {
    virtual void hello_world();
};
class bar : public foo {
    void hello_world();
};
```

My question is: is there any performance difference if I make it virtual
for `bar`'s `hello_world`? It will become this:

```
class foo {
    virtual void hello_world();
};
class bar : public foo {
    virtual void hello_world();
};
```

I will mainly call `hello_world` from `bar`.
I know virtual function will make functions slow
because we do run time look up. But for this case, is there any difference?

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what you're asking since your example code isn't syntactically valid. But if you're asking whether adding the `virtual` keyword to a function that's already virtual (because it's inherited as a virtual function) changes performance, then the answer is no - the `virtual` keyword has no effect in that case at all.

Comment: You can actually measure this if you set up a reasonable test.  I remember doing exactly that a few years back, and found that the overhead wasn't worth worrying about.  Maybe it is worth worrying about for your application, but I doubt it.

Comment: This question should not have been closed.  It is specific, answerable and on-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling a virtual function in a context where the class may, indeed, be polymorphic always has some performance impact compared to a function with the same logic that can be inlined. The primary reasons are that there is a small overhead calling a function, a small overhead in looking up which function needs to be called, and a major loss of optimization opportunities. The last point is typically the most expensive one.

The original example didn't compile, i.e., it is pretty clear that no performance analysis was done, yet. Worry about the performance impact once you have measured that your code runs too slow and that the specific call is, indeed, in the area where the performance problem comes from.

Comment: The hello_word() members in his code are both private virtual regardless if he uses virtual keyword on bar::hello_word() or not.

Comment: To my reading, this overplays (a bit) the performance hit taken by virtual functions on most real world applications, let alone toy applications.

Comment: Öö Tiib: Yes, the whether the functions are `private` doesn't matter: If a derived class has a function matching the signature of a `virtual` function of a base class, it overrides the function.

Comment: @JohnDibling: I didn't claim that there is a big overhead. Depending on what is done in the function it may or may not matter. However, if tiny virtual functions called in inner loops this can be a problem. For example, calling an increment(), an at_end(), and a get_value() `virtual` functions when iterating over a vector-like data structure can have a major performance impact. Making a function formatting a couple of numbers `virtual` or not will probably not have a measurable impact.

Comment: Oh, I just give an example here. In my application the hello_world is performance critical...

Comment: Could I make the conclusion now? If the base function is virtual, then the inherited function is virtual, no matter I add the keyword virtual or not?

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld: Assuming the signatures are identical (the return type may be covariant, though), then, yes, it doesn't matter if you use `virtual` or `override` in the derived class: the function will be an override.